# x86 SIMD instructions 16 byte alignment in assembly (Without C intrinsics)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, simd, memory-alignment

Let's say that I have an array of **8 byte** elements of **unknown length** from memory passed to my assembly function. I want to do some **128 bit** SIMD operations (up to SSE4) on it. It is better that the memory is 16 byte aligned. So I would check if the array is aligned and then depending on that use *movaps* or *movups*.

I know you can check 16-byte alignment with:

```
test dil, 0xf        ; rdi stores address of array
```

---

If it isn't 16-byte aligned, is it good or useful to also check if it's 8-byte aligned, which would mean that it's an odd multiple of 8?

```
test dil, 0x7           ; ZF=1 here after rdi&0xf !=0 implies rdi%16 == 8
```

And if that is true then should I do an extra step on the first element of array and then *movaps* to load the array elements? And otherwise should I just use unaligned operations like *movups*?

Does it work like this?

Comment: You are asking quite a few questions at once.  Usually, each Stack Overflow question should ask a single question.  That said, yes, it is worth ensuring alignment in the beginning.  That said, to check for 8 byte alignment, use `test rdi, 0x7` not `0x8`.

Comment: @fuz: Based on the text, I think they actually want to check for an **odd multiple of 8**, i.e. being 1 element away from 16-byte alignment.  `test dil, 8` would only work for that after you'd established 8-byte alignment with `test dil, 0x7`, so yeah this is broken after finding it's *not* a multiple of 16.  `ptr & 8` could be true for a pointer offset by 15 bytes from an alignment boundary, not 8.   edited to fix the code in the question so the answer can talk about the real point of the question without that distraction.

Comment: If you have a pre-Nehalem Intel CPU, you should never use use `movups`, since it is actually cheaper to split loads into the upper and lower half (using `movhps`/`movlps`/`movsd`). How likely do you expect memory which is not 8 byte aligned? What order of magnitude is your array length typically? (<100 bytes? a few MB?)

Comment: @chtz it is for a school project and the probabilities of not 8 byte aligned isnt specified, but the order is surely bigger than 100 bytes

Comment: @trollinator The best way to get good advice about performance programming is to explain what the context of the operation is.  This way, it is possible to understand what you attempt to do and what your constraints are.  More often than not, performance problems must be tackled by viewing the problem from a different perspective.  By not providing context, you deny this possibility and make it hard to give anything but the most general responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your arrays are *usually* aligned by 16, it's probably best not to do even more checking to look for the odd-start case, just use your unaligned version unless it's a lot worse for some reason.

However, if they're usually aligned by 8 (but unknown whether they're aligned by 16), then **you may be able to get away with only checking for alignment by 8 and branchlessly handling the maybe-unaligned first iteration for the aligned case, see below**.  (Otherwise just fall back to your fully unaligned case.)

If overlap isn't a problem (e.g. c[] = a[]+b[], or a memset-like store or whatever), a good technique is to *always* do a first vector with unaligned load/store, then advance to the first aligned vector (`add rdi, 16` / `and rdi, -16`).  If the input was aligned, this won't overlap.  Otherwise, it partially overlaps and the store buffer + L1d cache handle it efficiently.

This keeps the cost minimal for the aligned case, and avoids the chance of branch mispredicts.

Rounding a pointer up/down to an alignment boundary is cheap, just an `and`, but you do have the code-size cost of peeling a whole copy of the loop body.  So it's not totally free as far as startup overhead, but at least this kind of startup overhead can overlap with a cache miss from the data.

---

But note that a lot of SIMD functions have multiple pointer inputs that can be misaligned relative to each other.  In that case, the standard advice is to align the output and keep using `movups` for inputs.  Although if the front-end is the bottleneck, you might choose to reach an alignment boundary for the input so you can fold a memory source operand into an ALU instruction like `xorps xmm0, [rdi]` and use `movups` store.

But if anything other than the front-end, e.g. cache or memory throughput, are a bottleneck, then you more often want to align the destination.  Intel's optimization manual has some advice about this.  Some of the reason is that load throughput is typically 2x store throughput (until IceLake), so the load hardware can more readily absorb the extra work for split loads.  Also, storing a full cache line with fewer stores can help reduce cases where a line gets evicted (written back) but then you store to it again and it has to get fetched + dirtied and eventually written-back again, instead of just fetched.

Comment: I assume, OP can't even guarantee that the memory is at least 8 byte aligned (i.e., overlapping load/store won't help)

Comment: @chtz: Thanks, I forgot to describe how this lets you minimize branching: it means you only have to check `test dil, 7` to check for 8-byte alignment, and then branchlessly fall into your aligned-by-16 loop.  Otherwise you jump to your unaligned version of the loop.  It's not always worth having 2 versions at all, though, but yes thanks, good point that if *elements* might not be naturally aligned, you need a fallback (if you choose to have an aligned version at all) unless the operation is pure bitwise (like XOR) so element boundaries don't actually matter.